# What do the OWLs and NEWTs measure?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter series, do OWLs and NEWTs measure a wizard/witch’s level of magical ability?

Comment: @amarillo nice job with the edit. VTRO if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I'm pretty sure that OWLs and NEWTs are the direct equivalent of the [O and A-levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Ordinary_Level) in the UK educational system:

> The O Level (Ordinary Level) is a subject-based qualification conferred as part of the General Certificate of Education. It was introduced as part of British educational reform in the 1950s alongside the more in-depth and academically rigorous A-level (official title of qualification: General Certificate of Education - Advanced Level) in England, Wales and Northern Ireland.

Since the books are set in the UK and the educational system of Wizardry closely resembles the boarding schools and educational system of the British Muggles, it makes sense that they would also have the equivalents of A and O levels. In fact, the OWLs and NEWTS were taken at about the same age as Muggles would sit the O and A-levels, so the parallelism is quite clear. Even the names are similar ([source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ordinary_Wizarding_Level)):

> An Ordinary Wizarding Level (often abbreviated O.W.L.) is a subject-specific test taken during Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry students' fifth year, administrated by the Wizarding Examinations Authority. The score made by a student on a particular O.W.L. determines whether or not he or she will be allowed to continue taking that subject in subsequent school years.

And no, they don't measure magical ability, but magical knowledge. They're just like the exams you had in school, their objective is to measure how well you have learned the lessons you've been taught.

Comment: "... to measure how well you can regurgitate what your professor crammed into you". Fixed that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**They test educational achievement, as opposed to magical talent.** In theory, of course: obviously a naturally talented witch or wizard will likely do better on their O.W.L.s or N.E.W.T.s, much as a talented Muggle will often do well on the SAT, O-Levels, and other such standardized tests.

For example, Snape, speaking of the O.W.L. in Potions, suggests that it is meant to assess what students have learned from his class:

> “I think it appropriate to remind you that next June you will be
> sitting an important examination, **during which you will prove how much
> you have learned** about the composition and use of magical potions.
> Moronic though some of this class undoubtedly are, I expect you to
> scrape an ‘Acceptable’ in your O.W.L., or suffer my . . .
> displeasure.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

Similarly, McGonagall emphasizes the importance of hard work in preparing for O.W.L.s, and asserts that *everyone* in her class can pass, so long as they study diligently.

> “You cannot pass an O.W.L.,” said Professor McGonagall grimly,
> “without serious application, practice, and study. I see no reason why
> everybody in this class should not achieve an O.W.L. in
> Transfiguration as long as they put in the work.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*